# How to remove file using fs in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, fs

i am trying remove file from the dir for that i tried below fs unlink method however it does not remove the file what is correct method of `fs` to use to remove file.

main.js

```
 try {
      const npmdir = `${process.cwd()}/${this.props.appName}`;
      process.chdir(npmdir);
      this.npmInstall();
      checkFilePath(this.props);
      if(this.props.sandboxEnv === "NO") {
        const sourceUrls = `${process.cwd()}/${"Jenkinsfile_CD_sandbox"}`;
        fs.unlinkSync(sourceUrls);
        console.log(err);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: your `sourceUrls` looks a bit funky are you sure it's correct and also provide file extension in the path.

Comment: @ShivamSood yes path is correct

Comment: Whats seems to be the error?

Comment: What is the EXACT error you get?  That will tell you why it wasn't able to delete the file.

Comment: Also, `fs.unlinkSync()` removes a single file, not a directory.